# How to align spans or text in paragraph from end to start

Tags: html, css, styles

I wonder if there is a simple CSS solution to start a content of paragraph from the end of it. I've tried ***text-align***, ***text-align-last***, ***text-orientation*** *and other properties* that might do the trick, but didn't find any luck so far.

This is the code snippet I have:

```html
<p class="tags_holder">
  <span class="record_tag">HTML5 canvas</span>
  <span class="record_tag">Adoby Animation</span>
  <span class="record_tag">Timelines</span>
  <span class="record_tag">Flash Movie</span>
  <span class="record_tag">Event Sounds</span>
</p>
```

[image: 1]

So it wraps spans taking last span to the second line. **What I want is** to have four of them on the last line taking the wrapping one to the first line. Like starting the paragraph from the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex` with `flex-direction` to achieve this. Set your **parent** element to `display: flex`. Then use `flex-direction: row-reverse`, this will literally reverse the content of the parent. On the `flex-wrap` property, you can use `wrap-reverse`. Pretty sure this is what you're looking for.

```css
.tags_holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  width: 550px;
  background: #222;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.record_tag {
  margin: .5rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  background: #333;
  color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<p class="tags_holder">
  <span class="record_tag">HTML5 canvas</span>
  <span class="record_tag">Adoby Animation</span>
  <span class="record_tag">Timelines</span>
  <span class="record_tag">Flash Movie</span>
  <span class="record_tag">Event Sounds</span>
</p>
```

Another way to do this would be to use display grid.

```css
.tags_holder {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "five . . ." 
    "four three two one";
  width: 550px;
  background: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.five {
  grid-area: five;
}

.four {
  grid-area: four;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
}

.one {
  grid-area: one;
}

.record_tag {
  margin: .5rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  background: #333;
  color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<p class="tags_holder">
  <span class="record_tag one">HTML5 canvas</span>
  <span class="record_tag two">Adoby Animation</span>
  <span class="record_tag three">Timelines</span>
  <span class="record_tag four">Flash Movie</span>
  <span class="record_tag five">Event Sounds</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Tried this too. It does revert rows from left to write, but it doesn't revert the lines. It still wraps the last span to the second line, but I need to start from the end of paragraph, so that there are four span in the last line and the wrapping one in the first.

Comment: @AlexandrPasko I added the `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse` and it does this --> ***I need to start from the end of paragraph, so that there are four span in the last line and the wrapping one in the first.***

Comment: Nice, that exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexandrPasko awesome, glad I was able to help out, if this is what you were looking for, feel free to mark as answered and happy coding ;)